# Displaying Result in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck with how to display the result in windows forms application.

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
            {
                txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var result = File.ReadAllLines(@txtFileName.Text).Select(s => s.Contains(txt_search.Text));


        }
```

I want to show the search result as a list. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What about putting a list view on your form and fill it?

Comment: What sort of list?  A list box?  A label?  An editable list in a multiline textbox? Something else?

Comment: It can be anything which can show my search result as a list like line by line.

Comment: You should call Dispose when done with the dialog form.

Answer (score 1):

one simple way to do it is to just have a text box which gets updated once the search completes.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length; //Set the current caret position at the end
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret(); //Now scroll it automatically
    }

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var result = File.ReadAllLines(@txtFileName.Text).Select(s => s.Contains(txt_search.Text));

    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(result.ToString()); //---> Appends the Text to the Rich Text Box, you may want to change the variable result(i hope its not a collection)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the above form, if you had a multiline text box you can show them with

```
    private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = File.ReadAllLines(@txtFileName.Text).Select(s => s.Contains(txt_search.Text));
        texbox1.Lines = result.ToArray();
    }
```

but it really does depend what you intend to do with the data, a text box is fine if no further action is required.

Answer (score 1):

One nice way of doing this might be to have a, "drop-down," style combo box containing your search results. You get this from Toolbox/Common Controls/ComboBox. Then, populate the box with the items in your list (assuming you have a list) as follows.

```
foreach(var resultString in myList)
{
    myComboBox.Add(resultString);
}
```

Hope this helps.